# Odoo: how to use domain with group in XML?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

I'm very new in odoo.

I have created a group named "group_food_manager", and a model named "food_account".
Now I want to create a list/tree view that :

1. shows the account of the current user.
2. shows all the accounts if current user is a member of the `group_food_manager` group.

Here is the action of the list/tree view:

```
<record id="food_account_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Accounts List</field>
        <field name="res_model">food_management.food_account</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <!--<field name="domain">[('user_id', '=', uid)]</field>-->   <---- This works
        <field name="domain">['|', ('user_id', '=', uid), ('group_food_manager', 'in', '?????']</field>  <- I don't know how to write it...
    </record>
```

So, is it possibile to use domian with group in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 2 groups: `group_food_user` and `group_food_manager`. Now you can create 2 record rules (`ir.rule`) the same way as for `sale.order`.
You will find a nice example at [sale_security](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/sale/security/sale_security.xml#L90).

Comment: Thanks it works! However I need another group and  to add users to `group_food_user` manually... I tried to create a rule without setting `groups` to make it global, so normal users can only see their personal accounts by default. But the rule also infect food managers, that's not what I want. How can I get around it?

Comment: Global rules won't work for your scenario, that's why i didn't propose it. The next possibility is to override search() on the model you want to restrict. You could do a group check before searching or filter the normal search afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groups_id` field.

```
<field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('module_name.group_food_manager'))]"/>
```